# How can I create definition of of real class?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

If I have a class:

in file "BigClass.ts":

```
class BigClass{
  /// a lot of properties and methods here, I mean, a lot
}
window['big'] = new BigClass();
```

And I would like to declare global one in "Big.d.ts":

```
declare let big:BigClass;
```

TS won't let me do it, because I can define declared variables only using interfaces from .d files too.

But this class is very big, I don't want to create an interface for it, where I'll repeat each and every prop and method... Is there a way around it?

Or maybe there is another way of declaring global variable, based on existing class that I am unaware of?

Comment: FYI: `tsc -d` is able to generate `.d.ts` from `.ts`.

Comment: Right, but I am changing the class constantly, I don't want to change the interface all the time too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to simply put `declare let big:BigClass;` in  `BigClass.ts`, and not in a d.ts file. It's perfectly legal.

This is assuming BigClass.ts is not a module, meaning it has no import\export statements. If it's not a module, other files would also "see" the declare statement.

However this is a bad practice since you relay on the fact that `window` just happens to be the global object in the browser.

the better way:

```
//file: BigClass.ts

class BigClass{
}

interface Window {
  big: BigClass;
}
window.big = new BigClass();
```

And since modules are really really more nice to work with, here's how you do this with modules:

```
//file: BigClass.ts

export class BigClass{
}
declare global {
  interface Window {
    big: BigClass;
  }
}
window.big = new BigClass();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Yes, this class is in a module that uses import/export, I tried all three methods you provided to declare it and in all cases another .ts file complains `Cannot find name 'big'`...

Comment: @shal what about `window.big` from another file? (talking about the last method I showed). 

Or alternatively, if you really want a global var, try `declare global {const big: BigClass}`

Comment: Perfect, now it did work!!! At last! I know, I should not post meaningless "thank you" comments here, but in this case it's irresistible :)

Answer (score 0):

> And I would like to declare global one in "Big.d.ts":

Why you would like to do this?
If you will declare any instance of this class, ts will already know everything about this class.
And also avoid global variables.
`const big = new BigClass();`

Comment: I know that I should avoid global classes, but I am translating a huge JavaScript project to TS, almost totally translated, but it uses global variables (not too many, but extensively). Alright, I'll have to go and generate an interface, no other choice now...